# Speech recognition API duplicated phrases on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, speech-recognition, webkitspeechrecognition

I found, that [speech recognition API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/9a0075d25326/speechapi.html#speechreco-result) duplicates result phrases on my Android (and does not duplicate on desktop).

For each phrase said, it returns two results. First one is

[image]

and the second one is

[image]

As you see, in the second return, phrase is duplicated, each copy is marked as `final` and second one is beyond `resultIndex`. In first return there is only one copy, it is `final` and it is beyond `resultIndex`.

I would take only second return, but the problem is that it happens on mobile Chrome, but does not happen on desktop `Chrome`. Desktop `Chrome` returns only first return.

So, the question is: is this by design behavior? Then how to distinguish single final phrase then commonly for all computers?

Or may be this is some error like sound echo, then the question is how to avoid/check echo?

**UPDATE**

Html is follows:

```
<input id="recbutton" type="button" value="Recognize">
<div id="output">

  <div>
    Initial text
  </div>

</div>
```

Code is follows:

```
var recognition = null;
var recognitionStarted = false;
var printcount = 1;
var lastPhrase = null;

$(function() {
  attachRecognition();
});

$('#recbutton').click( function() {
    if( !recognitionStarted ) {
    recognition.start();
  }
  else {
    recognition.stop();
  }
});

function printOut(text) {
    var id = 'printcount' + printcount;
  printcount++;

    $('#output').append(
    "<div id='" + printcount + "'>" + text + "</div>"
  );

    $("#output").animate({ scrollTop: $("#output").prop('scrollHeight')});

  return printcount;

}


function attachRecognition() {

  if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {

    $('button').prop('disabled', true);

    recognition = null;

  } else {
    $('button').prop('disabled', false);

    recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = true;
    recognition.lang = "en-US";

    recognition.onstart = function(event) {
      recognitionStarted = true;
      printOut("speech recognition started");
    };

    recognition.onend = function(event) {
            recognitionStarted = false;
            printOut("speech recognition stopped");
    };

    recognition.onresult = function(event) {

      var finalPhrase = '';
      var interimPhrase = '';
      var result;
      var printcount;

      for(var i=0; i<event.results.length; ++i) {
        result = event.results[i];
        if( result.isFinal ) {
          finalPhrase = finalPhrase.trim() + ' ' + result[0].transcript;
        }
        else {
          interimPhrase = interimPhrase.trim() + ' ' + result[0].transcript;
        }
      }

      if( !lastPhrase ) {
        printcount = printOut('');
        lastPhrase = $('#' + printcount);
      }

      lastPhrase.html(finalPhrase.trim() + ' ' + interimPhrase.trim());

      if( finalPhrase.trim() ) {
        lastPhrase = null;
      }


    };
  }
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dimskraft/envwao8o/1/

Answer (score 5):

The results provided on Chrome mobile regarding the `result.isFinal` property seem to have a bug or in any case to differ from the ones on Chrome desktop. A possible workaround is to check the confidence attribute of the (first) alternative:

```
onResultHandler(event) {
    let i = event.resultIndex;
    let result = event.results[i];
    let isFinal = result.isFinal && (result[0].confidence > 0);
}
```

It also looks like that sometimes the final result is emitted twice (with the same `confidence` value), in that case you may want to debounce it or just process the first event, like this:

```
if (isFinal) {
    transcript = result[0].transcript;

    if(transcript == lastDebounceTranscript) {
        return;
    }

    lastDebounceTranscript = transcript;

}
```

where `lastDebounceTranscript` is a variable that you initialize outside of the scope of the event handler

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It appears that interim results are marked isFinal on android but do have that confidence attr set to 0. So I handle results with confidence 0 as interim results.

Comment: I don't have an android to check it on, and I had installed many emulators with no success (non of them supported using the mic), and based on your answer I just pushed code to production without checking it... I sure hope it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
recognition.continuous = false;
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/envwao8o/4/

Comment: recognition.continuous = false; will not accept continuous input from user.